# Spring boot 1.4.2 command line args not overriding test-application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am working on a spring boot based application (version 1.4.2).

There is a desire to configure our many build pipelines to inject a value for spring.datasource.password to override what is in application-test.properties.

What I've found is that if I do:

mvn test -Dspring.datasource.password="blah" without the spring.datasource.password being defined in application-test.properties, it works fine. No problem.

However, if I have an entry within application-test.properties, the override does not appear to work and it uses the value defined in the properties file.

Is there a way I can get this approach to work? As far as I know, spring should always use the command line args first unless you configure it not to (which isn't  the case in this app).

I could use profiles, but we have multiple pipelines and I'd rather have one application-test.properties file with a password for a developer to get up and running locally and then be able to override that value within my build pipelines to use a password for another database.

The other thing of note, which I don't believe to be an issue is that I'm using Spock for my tests rather than JUnit.